# Java Float Trigonometric Optimization

Tags: java, math, optimization, floating-point, trigonometry

I'm writing my own 3D rendering engine. Following general knowledge I am currently using floating point values as my base of operations. For the rotation matrices I however require the trigonometric functions in the java.lang.Math library, which uses double values as in and output.

I was wondering if you could implement an optimized version of the trigonometric functions using floating point values, improving performance.

Comment: Internally, you should use double values. Why would you want to use float rather than double?

Comment: While performance-wise, the computation doesn't seem to be affected by either choice, floats save 50% in storage since they are 32bit instead of 64.

Comment: Yes, they save 50% in storage. Just how many 100's of millions of points do you expect to have? Doubles have better precision than floats. And yes, I do 3d graphics on Blender, sometimes.

Comment: Well, while this is true, I think for a 3D game engine, 6dps of precision is far sufficient. I mean what do the extra decimal places help you with?

Comment: Do you ever plan to rotate or scale the objects at all? Trust me, you need all the precision you can get for free.

Comment: I just trusted you and converted all to doubles. Let's hope your advice was good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.sin()`, `Math.cos()`, `Math.tan()` are implemented in assembly, so any custom implementation would be at a severe disadvantage.

The conversions from `float` to `double` and viceversa have a negligible performance impact. So, if you want to use `float` to save memory, go ahead. However, considering this is Java, I would not worry much about saving memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can. The `Math` methods, like `sin()`, are `native`.

You can write your own `native` methods in your own class, then benchmark to see if you actually gained anything, because JIT might know how to optimize the standard `Math` methods, but can't optimize custom `native` methods.